# WPF: Binding to custom DependencyProperty not possible

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to add a custom DataProperty to DataGridTextColumn.

I'v inherited a Custom Class and added a Dependency Property as follows:

```
public class CustomDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(CustomDataGridTextColumn), new PropertyMetadata(0));


}
```

I set the Binding with the following code in my MainWindow Constructor right after InitComponents();:

```
CustomDataGridTextColumn test = new CustomDataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "1. Operand",
    Binding = new Binding("Operand1") //<- This works
};

test.SetValue(CustomDataGridTextColumn.MyPropertyProperty, new Binding("Operand1")); // <- This doesn't
```

When starting my Application I get a "System.ArgumentExcpetion" at "test.SetValue(...)" stating ""System.Windows.Data.Binding" is not a valid value for the property "MyProperty"" (Note: This error message is translated by me, because there is no error code like "CS1324").

As far as I am concerned every Dependency Property should support DataBindings?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this must be done in code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to establish a Binding in code behind, you'll have to use the [`BindingOperations.SetBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx) method instead of `SetValue`:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    test,
    CustomDataGridTextColumn.MyPropertyProperty,
    new Binding("Operand1"));
```

Comment: Unfortunality there is no SetBinding Method for DataGridTextColumn

Comment: See edit, classes derived from FrameworkElement provide a [SetBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598270.aspx) method for convenience.

Comment: This works for me now. Thank you and have a nice day.